# Can i switch of <link href=""> using django?

Tags: css, django, button, conditional-statements, frameworks

Is it possible to make a switch button that change my stylesheet using django framework?

By example, in my head HTML I got this:

```
<link href="{% static 'website/assets/css/style_dark.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

And I would like to get the bellow stylesheet IF my button ( on the body HTML is clicked)

```
<link href="{% static 'website/assets/css/style_light.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

'''

Comment: Normally you define simply CSS selectors that are only active if the button is active and vice-versa.

Comment: Could you please show me an example so that I can apply it? I have difficulties ( and thanks for your help mate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without reloading page it won't work. (Because Django puts those things during rendering the page).

Another way around you can add on button click some URL with parameter (e.g. `<a href="/?style={{ style }}">`) which will lead to the same view.
So in Django, when view was called with this parameter - you do the trick:

```
def my_view(request):
    style = request.GET.get('style')
    if style == 'dark':
        context['style'] == 'light'
    elif style == 'light':
        context['style'] == 'dark'
    return HttpResponse(loader.get_template('template.html').render(context, request))
```

and in template:

```
<link href="{% static 'website/assets/css/style_{{ style }}.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Though, it is kind of a work-around. (Better to do such things in front-end). But in general, it should do the trick.

Comment: I think im abble to integrate this in my project from your help ! Thanks mate !

Comment: @JonathanMichel, you're welcome. You might also consider to pass this parameter in Cookies instead of URL-parameter

Comment: I will work on this too, its a nice idea for learn, thanks ! Im still looking for to learn from your example, then try to integrate it, but its a real fighting right now xD I will keep working to make it work !